# Cannot Scrape IMDB after logging into personal profile using Scrapy?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

Following is my code. I am not able to scrape IMDB after I login successfully. The problem is that the after_login verifies that the Form request has worked but when I print the content of the page after login by making a new Request, it shows the main IMDB page and not the main IMDB page with user logged in.

```
"""
Attributes:
    name (str): essential attribute which specifies the name of the spider
    start_urls (list): the urls that are to be scraped

"""
name = 'IMDB_spider'
start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/ap/signin?clientContext=131-8656718-8097200&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.'
            'return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fap-signin-handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.ne'
            't%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=ey'
            'JvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl91cyIsInJlZGlyZWN0VG8iOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5pbWRiLmNvbS8_cmVmXz1sb2d'
            'pbiJ9&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http'
            '%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&&tag=imdbtag_reg-20']

def parse(self, response):
    """
    Scrapy's default method that handles all the downloaded response for
    each request made.

    Arguments:
        response (text): contains all data of the page and other helpful
        methods as well

    """
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': '*******', 'password': '****'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    """
    Default callback method that is called to authenticate when logging in
    to website.

    Arguments:
        response (text): contains all data of the page and other helpful
        methods as well

    """
    if "There was a problem." in response.body:
        print('Login Failed')
        return
    print('Login Success')
    return scrapy.Request(url="http://www.imdb.com",
                          callback=self.parse_imdb_page)

def parse_imdb_page(self, response):
    print response.body
```

Please help

Comment: At least remove your username and password :p

Comment: How are you sure that you are successfully logged in?

Comment: it prints "Login Success" if the "There was a problem" text is not present in html body. That is the message shown at failure to login.

Comment: Your check of testing whether it has logged in is quite poor. When testing your form request in shell I landed on a page asking me to enable cookies. Make sure cookies are enabled and focus on something that needs to be on the page that verifies you're logged in, instead of the other way around.

Comment: I have enabled cookies